# Fast way to extract columns from table and give them a specific format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following table :

```
          date id rank_year sales cost
 1: 2015-12-31  1         0   149  101
 2: 2014-12-31  1        -1   150  102
 3: 2013-12-31  1        -2   151  104
 4: 2012-12-31  1        -3   152  107
 5: 2011-12-31  1        -4   155   99
 6: 2015-12-31  2         0    84   55
 7: 2014-12-31  2        -2    83   55
 8: 2014-01-25  2        -3    80   56
 9: 2013-01-25  2        -4    81   57
10: 2012-01-25  2        -5    97   58

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(as.IDate(c("2015-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2013-12-31",
                             "2012-12-31", "2011-12-31", "2015-12-31",
                             "2014-12-31", "2014-01-25", "2013-01-25",
                             "2012-01-25")),
                  c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                  c("0", "-1", "-2", "-3", "-4", "0", "-2", "-3", "-4", "-5"),
                  c(149, 150, 151, 152, 155, 84, 83, 80, 81, 97),
                  c(101, 102, 104, 107, 99, 55, 55, 56, 57, 58))
setnames(DT, c("date", "id", "rank_year", "sales", "cost"))
```

I have to isolate every columns of this data.table in order to put the values in another format. I should have a new variable in my environment with sales as a name and that has the following format:

```
   id -19 -18 -17 -16 -15 -14 -13 -12 -11 -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1   0   1
1:  1 @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA 155 152 151 150 149 @NA
2:  2 @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA @NA  97  81  80  83 @NA  84 @NA
```

I would define the steps that I have to do as the following:

1. Create new variables for every column in DT and assign them the name of the column
2. The row of the new variables should be the `unique(DT$id)`
3. The columns should always be -19 to 1. It represents different `rank_year`
4. Add the values of DT in the good column by using `rank_year` for every new variables (Lookup)

I did the following code. It works but it is way too slow. It would take me more than 3 days to run the code on the real dataset.

```
unique.id <- data.frame(unique(DT$id))
variable.names <- colnames(DT)

rank <- data.frame((-19:1))
colnames(rank) <- "rank_year"

col.names <- factor(rank[[1]])  
row.names <- unique(DT$id)

for (i in 1:length(variable.names)) {

  variable.results <- matrix(data = NA,
                             nrow = dim(unique.id)[1],
                             ncol = dim(rank)[1])
  colnames(variable.results) <- col.names
  row.names(variable.results) <- row.names

  for (j in 1:length(row.names)) {
    temp.data <- DT[DT$id == row.names[j], ]
    temp.data <- data.frame(temp.data)
    temp.data <- data.frame(temp.data["rank_year"], temp.data[i]) 
    temp.data <- merge(rank, temp.data, by = "rank_year", all.x = TRUE)
    variable.results[j, ] <- t(data.frame(temp.data[, 2]))
    variable.results[is.na(variable.results)] <- "@NA"
  }
  rm(temp.data)

  assign(variable.names[i], variable.results)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic `dcast` operation with the added complication that you need to pad the original data, which you can do with a merge:

```
dcast(
  DT[CJ(rank_year = as.character(-19:1), id = id, unique = TRUE), on = c("rank_year", "id")],
  id ~ rank_year, 
  value.var = "sales")
#   id  -1 -10 -11 -12 -13 -14 -15 -16 -17 -18 -19  -2  -3  -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9   0  1
#1:  1 150  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 151 152 155 NA NA NA NA NA 149 NA
#2:  2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  83  80  81 97 NA NA NA NA  84 NA
```

Note that the ordering is alphabetic because your `rank_year` is a character vector. Make it an integer if you need numeric sorting. Or you could just order the columns afterwards. Also, you should not define `NA` values as characters.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that! For a specific reason, I absolutely need the `NA` in character but thanks for the information.

Comment: If you "need" this, you don't need it in R. Use the `na` parameter of `write.table` when you export this result.

Comment: I did not think about it! Excellent Point